# Jradiobutton in multiple groups

Tags: java, swing, radio-group, jradiobutton

I am attempting to have four jradiobuttons that are all connected. There are two teams that each have the option of left or right. A team should only have one of the options selected, while at the same time the team's should not have the same option selected (ie. Both left or both right). I tried using four jradiobutton groups, placing the buttons for the team in a group as well as having the lefts in a group and the rights in a group.

For example, if I have four JRadioButtons A,B,C,D,

A  B

C  D

I need A and B to be grouped, C and D to be grouped, A and C to be grouped, and B and D to be grouped, so that the only possible combinations are A and D being selected, or B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really just use **ButtonGroup** for this. It's a bit more complicated.

I would have a ButtonGroup for the two horizontal lines like so :

```
ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(A);
bg.add(B);

ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(C);
bg.add(D);
```

And then add an **actionlistener**  on the radio buttons. The actionListener will listen on all radio buttons. If A is clicked then move selection to D in the lower row. Or if C is selected move upper row selection to B. Etc.

Comment: UPDATE: on second thoughts you don't really need the ButtonGroups at all. Just listen on D and select A, C select B etc.